# Ball not throw proper direction unity3d?

Tags: unity

[image]I am making a game where the player throw basketball in 3d view but it may not throw proper.So I need ball throw proper on z direction with curve move when player mouse up.

[Reference Link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dumadugames.basketball)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI; 
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class BallController : MonoBehaviour
{

 public static BallController instance;

 [SerializeField]
  private GameObject Player;

 private Vector3 touchStart;

 private Vector3 touchEnd;

 private Vector3 screenPoint;

 private Vector3 offset;

void OnMouseUp ()
{
   ThrowBall ();
}
public void ThrowBall ()
{
    touched = true;
    Vector3 pos1 = new Vector3 ();
    Vector3 pos2 = new Vector3 ();
    touchStart.z = Camera.main.nearClipPlane - (.2f);
    touchEnd.z = Camera.main.nearClipPlane - (0.08f);

    pos1 = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (touchStart);
    pos2 = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (touchEnd);

    Vector3 v = pos2 - pos1; 
    v.z = 0.02f;

    Player.GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().AddForce (v * 600, ForceMode.Impulse);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please describe in what particular way the ball "may not throw proper"?  Images, diagrams, or animations / video often help communicate the problem when it's a visual/spatial or movement issue. Walk us through what happens, and how specifically it differs from what you want.

Comment: @ DMGregory Ya i give diagram what I want and I also give reference link of game

Comment: Remember, we've never seen your game. We don't know how the results you're getting now are different from the target reference game you've linked unless you explain it. What about your current movement do you need to change?

Comment: @ DMGregory thanks for replay In my current code When I mouse up ball throw but ball direct throw on z direction  I want to ball should throw z direction with slightly curve.

Comment: So, what have you tried so far? Reducing the z component of your throw vector, multiplying the y component, increasing gravity? Again, remember that we don't have your whole project open in front of us to play with and tune, the only things we know about it and how it's responding to your tuning attempts are what you tell us. So you need to help us understand where your problem is.

Comment: okay I give you screen shot what I want of game